# split a table into several with Beautiful Soup [Python]

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I need your help with a problem which I can't find out...

I have an html Table with tr and td:

**for example:**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
     <td>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
      <br />
      <h2>
       Macros
      </h2>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      #define&nbsp;
     </td>
     <td>
      <a class="el" href="#g3e3da223d2db3b49a9b6e3ee6f49f745">
       SND_LSTINDIC
      </a>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="mdescLeft">
      &nbsp;
     </td>
     <td class="mdescRight">
      liste sons indication
      <br />
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
      <br />
      <h2>
       Définition de type
      </h2>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="memItemLeft" nowrap="nowrap" align="right" valign="top">
      typedef void(*&nbsp;
     </td>
     <td class="memItemRight" valign="bottom">
      <a class="el" href="#g73cba8bd62d629eb05495a5c1a7b2844">
       f_sndChangeFunc
      </a>
      )(
      <a class="el" href="#g4ab7db37a42f244764583a63997489a8">
       e_sndSound
      </a>
      i_eSound,
    aBOOL
    i_bStart,
    aBYTE
    i_byDisableModule)
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="mdescLeft">
      &nbsp;
     </td>
     <td class="mdescRight">
      Fonction rappel sur départ/arrêt bip.
      <a href="#g73cba8bd62d629eb05495a5c1a7b2844">
      </a>
      <br />
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
      <br />
      <h2>
       Énumérations
      </h2>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="memItemLeft" nowrap="nowrap" align="right" valign="top">
      enum &nbsp;
     </td>
     <td class="memItemRight" valign="bottom">
      <a class="el" href="#g4ab7db37a42f244764583a63997489a8">
       e_sndSound
      </a>
      {
      }
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="mdescLeft">
      &nbsp;
     </td>
     <td class="mdescRight">
      identificateurs sons
      <a href="group__Sound.html#g4ab7db37a42f244764583a63997489a8">
       Plus de détails...
      </a>
      <br />
     </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I try to split this table by several one. I would like to get out

title and create a table with the following  lines.

For example the expected result here should be this:

```
<h2>
  Macros
</h2>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
     <td>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
      <br />
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      #define&nbsp;
     </td>
     <td>
      <a class="el" href="#g3e3da223d2db3b49a9b6e3ee6f49f745">
       SND_LSTINDIC
      </a>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="mdescLeft">
      &nbsp;
     </td>
     <td class="mdescRight">
      liste sons indication
      <br />
     </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h2>
    Définition de type
  </h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
     <td class="memItemLeft" nowrap="nowrap" align="right" valign="top">
      typedef void(*&nbsp;
     </td>
     <td class="memItemRight" valign="bottom">
      <a class="el" href="#g73cba8bd62d629eb05495a5c1a7b2844">
       f_sndChangeFunc
      </a>
      )(
      <a class="el" href="#g4ab7db37a42f244764583a63997489a8">
       e_sndSound
      </a>
      i_eSound,
    aBOOL
    i_bStart,
    aBYTE
    i_byDisableModule)
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="mdescLeft">
      &nbsp;
     </td>
     <td class="mdescRight">
      Fonction rappel sur départ/arrêt bip.
      <a href="#g73cba8bd62d629eb05495a5c1a7b2844">
      </a>
      <br />
     </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h2>
    Énumérations
  </h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
     <td class="memItemLeft" nowrap="nowrap" align="right" valign="top">
      enum &nbsp;
     </td>
     <td class="memItemRight" valign="bottom">
      <a class="el" href="#g4ab7db37a42f244764583a63997489a8">
       e_sndSound
      </a>
      {
      }
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="mdescLeft">
      &nbsp;
     </td>
     <td class="mdescRight">
      identificateurs sons
      <a href="group__Sound.html#g4ab7db37a42f244764583a63997489a8">
       Plus de détails...
      </a>
      <br />
     </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I use python and BeautifulSoup in order to parse my html code.
I tried with this first :

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
import sys
import os

soup = BeautifulSoup(allHtml)

for table in htmlSoup.findAll("table"):
   h2s = table.findAll("h2")
      if h2s is not []:      
         FirstH2 = True
         LastH2 = False
         for i, h2 in enumerate(h2s):
            if h2 is not []:
               LastH2 = ( i == len(h2s) - 1 )

               h2.parent.replaceWithChildren() # <td> deleted
               h2.parent.replaceWithChildren() # <tr> deleted
               print h2.parent
               if FirstH2:
                  h2.replaceWith( h2.prettify() + '<table>' )
                  #h2_tag_idx = h2.parent.contents.index(h2) # other method to add Tags
                  #h2.parent.insert(h2_tag_idx + 1, '<b>OK</b>')
               else:
                  h2.replaceWith( '</table>' + h2.prettify() + '<table>' )

               FirstH2 = False

print soup.prettify()
```

But no way, it replace my Tag  with the HTML équivalent ASCII code...

I also tried to get every contents in the table and after try to rebuild several table en put it again in the soup but it failed...

I also tried to get the table in a String and split the string with  as delimiter and reput all subTable into the soup but it failed too...

If someone has an idea, it would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the best way to resolve that would be to extract the table content, search all <h2>, delete <td> and <tr> which wrap <h2>, take all <tr> after <h2> until next <h2> and wrap them with <table> do this while last <h2>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this function and it works...

```
def getOutTitleFromTable(htmlSoup):
   for ii, table in enumerate(htmlSoup.findAll("table")):
      h2s = table.findAll("h2") # on cherche tous les <h2></h2> dans le tableau
      #print h2s
      if len(h2s) > 0: #si on a au moins 1 <h2> dans le tableau   
         FirstH2 = True
         LastH2 = False
         newTables = BeautifulSoup() # contiendra nos tableaux reconstitués
         for i, h2 in enumerate(h2s):
            if h2 is not []:
               LastH2 = ( i == len(h2s) - 1 )
               h2.parent.replaceWithChildren() # on supprime le <td>
               h2.parent.replaceWithChildren() # on supprime le <tr>

               idT = "table"+str(ii)+str(i) # création d'un id de tableau pour une meilleure lisibilité
               wrapTable = Tag(htmlSoup, "table")
               wrapTable["id"]=idT
               wrapTable["border"]=0
               wrapTable["cellpadding"]=0
               wrapTable["cellspacing"]=0
               #print h2.parent.contents.index(h2) # index du h2 dans l'arbre table
               table.insert(h2.parent.contents.index(h2)+1, wrapTable) # on ajoute <table></table> après chaque <h2>"title"</h2>
               #newTable = table.findAll("table")
               newTable = table.find(name="table", attrs={"id" : idT})
               fillTable = False
               #print table.findAll(["h2","tr"])
               for tr in table.findAll(["h2","tr"]):
                  if fillTable:
                     if tr in h2s:
                        #print "fin du nouveau tableau"
                        #print tr
                        fillTable = False
                        break
                     else:
                        if tr.find("h2") not in h2s:
                           #print "ajout d'une nouvelle ligne: "
                           newTable.contents.append(tr)
                           #print newTable.contents

                  if str(tr) == str(h2):
                     #print "Début du nouveau tableau"
                     #print tr
                     fillTable = True

               newTables.append(h2)
               newTables.append(newTable)

               #os.system("pause")

               #print h2
               #print FirstH2
               #print LastH2
               FirstH2 = False

         #print newTables
         table.contents = newTables
         table.name = "div" # On change la balise table en div... on triche mais je n'arrive absolument pas à retirer le wrap <table></table>
```

If someone has a better solution, I will enjoy look at it.

Bye